# How do app-specific protocols (like `zotero://`, 'goldendict://') work?

Tags: web, protocols, desktop-application

I noticed that some apps have their own protocols like `zotero://`, `goldendict://` etc. And some functions can be invoked by such url like that `zotero://open-pdf/library/items/AABBCCDD?annotation=[annotation-key]` can open a pdf in zotero. It will open a pdf when I type the url in a browser.

I know protocols like `http` have some RFCs and they can be recognized by all browsers. So I am wondering how do these app-specific protocols work? What are the principles and theories under this.

Thanks in advance!